# get current class instance

Tags: c#, class, instance

Ho do you get the current instance of a class?

The class have search method and cancel method.

Code example:

```
if (btnSearch.Text =="Search")
{
    Searcher srch = new Searcher();
    srch.Search();
    btnSearch.Text = "Cancel";
    return;
}
if (btnSearch.Text == "Cancel")
{
    //call a method in the instance above for example
   srch.Cancel();
}
```

I want to create the instance only when btnSearch.Text =="Search"; and when btnSearch.Text =="Cancel"; i want to call srch.Cancel();

////
Thanks to nmclean, problem solved, makes sense i had to declare the Search class at a higher scope to be able to access the current running instance.

Comment: What is meant by "the instance above"? An instance of `Searcher`?

Comment: Do you want to call method of `srch` from above scope?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please define "the current instance of a class".. You mean a singleton, or service locator, or...?

Comment: Store `srch` somewhere

Comment: There's no such thing as "the current instance". What if there were more than one instance? What if there were multiple threads?

Comment: The thing is, i only want to create the instance when btnSearch.Text =="Search"; since that class is doing things in the background, so its pretty much a different thread.

Comment: @NetInfo: Frankly, I do not understand what you are asking. If you only create the instance if `btnSearch.Text == "Search"` (which is what the above code is doing), then how do you expect that instance to be around if that condition *does not* apply? Also, while you have implied it, you still have not responded to our questions *what instance* (of which class?) you are actually referring to.

Comment: I also wouldn't depend on the text of the button. Instead, keep a "search-in-progress" flag around. You could also follow the suggestions below for raising the scope of `srch`, and use `srch != null` as your "search-in-progress" flag.

Comment: Is this code inside of an event handler for `btnSearch_Click` or something? If so, you should show that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `srch` variable must be declared at a higher scope than the function, otherwise it will not persist to the next time the function is called. Most likely this means it should be a field of the class:

```
class YourClass
{
    private Searcher srch;

    void YourMethod()
    {
        if (btnSearch.Text == "Search")
        {
            srch = new Searcher();
            srch.Search();
            btnSearch.Text = "Cancel";
            return;
        }
        if (btnSearch.Text == "Cancel")
        {
            srch.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After lots of debugging and trials, this worked like a charm. thanks a lot, sorry if there were any confusion.